# How could I find the radius of a circle in a Nx2 matrix, not using images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry

I am currently using bwboundaries to find shapes inside a binary image (nodules in a lung CT scan), however, I need to be able to identify circular objects which are probably the diaphragm. As a result, I have my circle perimeters stored in Nx2 matrices. I would like to know if there's any way I could find the radius and eccentricity of these shapes without having to create a new image first.

Comment: when you say circular, do you also include elliptical objects? Otherwise, there is no question of calculating eccentricity.

Comment: [This first google hit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9168-detect-circles-with-various-radii-in-grayscale-image-via-hough-transform) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `regionprops` on the binary image to find out some object's properties such as `EquivDiameter`, which is a scalar that specifies the diameter of a circle with the same area as the region, or `centroid` along with `extrema` to compute the mean radius.

From the Nx2 matrix, you can also take the (min, max) of the x-values and divide it by 2 to have the x-radius.

Comment: The min,max one is perfect for what I'm trying to do. I feel pretty dumb that that didn't occur to me! Thank you.